# I've overwritten a table in my database (locally), How can I stop this from deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, schema, database-migration

I have a table named Impressions and recently (in a dev branch) I installed the impressionist gem which has overwritten this table.

My master branch is now showing the overwritten version and not my original. Fortunately, I haven't deployed, so I still have the data.

Other than exporting data from live, creating a new table and importing again.. is there a way I can fix this?

It's worth saying that my Schema on the master branch kept my old table columns, but when I renamed the table (in an effort to stop it being overwritten when I merge from the dev branch) the renamed table had the columns from the impressionist gem.
Why is this? I have schema checked in to my version control and so I feel uncomfortable knowing that the things I'm editing on my dev branches are having and effect on my master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Rollback the database to one step by using the below command:

```
  rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

& exceute the below command

```
rails d impressionist
```

Comment: The rollback isn't working for me. I tried a bunch of things in a panic before asking the question.. so it's perhaps too late?